# Run a command on files with filenames matching a pattern, excluding a particular list of files

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

The following script searches files with the suffix `.tex` in a directory (i.e. TeX files), for the string `\RequireLuaTeX`, i.e. LuaTeX files in that directory, and creates a Bash array from the results.

It then runs the command `latexmk` on the files in that array.

I'd like to exclude a list of user defined files from this array, possibly declared as an array thus:

```
excludedfiles=(foo.tex bar.tex baz.tex)
```

I'm writing to solicit suggestions for clean ways to do this.

I quite like the approach of putting everything in an array. For one thing, it makes it easy to list the files before running commands on them. But I'm willing to consider other approaches.

```
#!/bin/bash                                
## Get LuaTeX filenames     
mapfile -t -d "" filenames < <(grep -Z -rL "\RequireLuaTeX" *.tex)

## Run `latexmk` on PDFTeX files.
for filename in "${filenames[@]}"
do
    base="${filename%.*}"
    rm -f "$base".pdf
    latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  "$base".tex
done
```

BACKGROUND AND COMMENTS:

TeX users may be confused by my question. So I'm explaining here what I was trying to do, and how I miswrote the question. I'm not changing it, because the change would invalidate the existing answers and create confusion.

I have a collection of LaTeX files. The older ones use PDFLaTeX. The newer ones mostly use PDFLaTeX. This question is about the PDFLaTeX ones. What I'm trying to do in my script is

a) Create a list of PDFLaTeX files. My LuaLaTeX files contain the string "\RequireLuaTeX" in them. Therefore, files which do not contain that string are PDFLaTeX files.

So, I am trying to create a list of LaTeX files which do not contain the string "\RequireLuaTeX" in them.

b) Run PDFLaTeX on them using `latexmk`.

My question has the following error. I wrote:

> The following script searches files with the suffix `.tex` in a directory (i.e. TeX files), for the string `\RequireLuaTeX`, i.e. LuaTeX files in that directory, and creates a Bash array from the results.

In fact I want files which do not contain that string, because as explained above, those correspond to my PDFLaTeX files.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but doesn't `latexmk` override the `.pdf` files by itself? Is there some special reason for the `rm`?

Comment: @Quasímodo Good point. I think I wanted to force a complete rebuild for some reason. Possibly that doesn't make sense. I'll review that, thanks. Note that AFAIK `latexmk` won't do a rebuild if the PDF file is newer than all the source file. It acts like `make` in that respect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-L` flag to Grep list files not matching a pattern. You want `-l` instead. Also, Grep needs to see double-backslash to match a single backslash.

Since you are in Bash, let us get hold of some useful constructs.

```
#!/bin/bash -
shopt -s globstar extglob
mapfile -t -d "" filenames < <(grep -Zl '\\RequireLuaTeX' ./**/!(foo|bar|baz).tex)
rm -f "${filenames[@]/%.tex/.pdf}"
latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode "${filenames[@]}"
```

- `**/!(foo|bar|baz).tex` expands to all files in the current directory tree that end in `.tex` but whose basename is not `foo.tex`, `bar.tex` nor `baz.tex`. Both [`globstar` and `extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) are required for this operation.
- [`"${filenames[@]/%.tex/.pdf}"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) expands to all elements of the array, substituting each **trailing** `.tex` by `.pdf`.

Since Latexmk can be given multiple files as arguments, we could skip for-loops.

Comment: What's the rationale for using `#!/bin/bash -`. A search suggests it's to stop users from passing additional arguments to Bash on the command line, but is this something that should be prevented?

Comment: That's a good question. If the script took a file as an argument, then one could say it is to prevent a file starting with hyphen, e.g. `-i`, from being interpreted as an option. But here we don't use arguments at all. Maybe @StéphaneChazelas can shed some light?

Comment: @Quasímodo, see [Why the "-" in the "#! /bin/sh -" shebang?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/351729)

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh`, you can turn an array into a pattern that matches any of its elements by joining with `|` with the `j[|]` parameter expansion flag the elements inside which the glob characters have been escaped with the `b` parameter expansion flag:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
excluded_file_names=(foo.tex bar.tex baz.tex)
excluded_file_names_pattern="(${(j[|])${(@b)excluded_file_names}})"

# here using the ~ extendedglob operator to apply the exclusion
tex_files=(
  ./**/(*.tex~$~excluded_file_names_pattern)
)

files=(
  ${(0)"$(grep -lZF '\RequireLuaTeX' $tex_files)"}
)
rm -f ${files/%tex/pdf}
latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode $files
```

Or you could use the `e` *glob qualifier* to check if the `t`ail of the file path is in the array:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
excluded_file_names=(foo.tex bar.tex baz.tex)

tex_files=(
  ./**/*.tex(^e['(($excluded_file_names[(Ie)$REPLY:t]))'])
)

files=(
  ${(0)"$(grep -lZF '\RequireLuaTeX' $tex_files)"}
)
rm -f ${files/%tex/pdf}
latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode $files
```

Answer (score 5):

The way I approach this kind of problem is to turn the list of file names/patterns into a hash that has instant lookup with no searching required. (Note that the `excludedFiles` patterns such as `z*.tex` are expanded as part of the assignment, not as part of the hashing loop. For example, if there are three files matching the `z*.tex` glob, then `excludedFiles` will contain three entries rather than the one pattern, and the hashing loop will iterate three times.)

```
# User configurable list of files and patterns
excludedFiles=(foo.tex bar.tex baz.tex z*.tex)

# Convert the list into a hash
declare -A excludedHash
for excludedFile in "${excludedFiles[@]}"
do
    [[ -e "$excludedFile" ]] && excludedHash[$excludedFile]=yes
done

# Processing
for filename in "${filenames[@]}"
do
    [[ -n "${excludedHash[$filename]}" ]] && continue    # Skip if filename is in hash

    base="${filename%.*}"
    rm -f "$base".pdf
    latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  "$base".tex
done
```

Comment: Note that the `z*.tex` is expanded once, when you set `excludedFiles=(...)`, not against basenames of `filenames[@]` (a hash lookup couldn't do that anyway).  That's fine for one directory, but does take O(n) work to list the directory and match the glob against every one. (And involves system calls.) Still, it does avoid a combinatorial explosion of work that you'd get if you naively match each filename against each of multiple patterns, and is probably a performance win if multiple of the `excludedFiles` entries are fixed strings.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, absolutely on all counts. I've amended the answer to try and make that explicitly clear

Answer (score 2):

With bash, one option is [`GLOBGIGNORE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion):

> The `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable may be used to restrict the set of
> file names matching a pattern. If `GLOBIGNORE` is set, each matching
> file name that also matches one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is
> removed from the list of matches. If the `nocaseglob` option is set,
> the matching against the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is performed without
> regard to case. The filenames `.` and `..` are always ignored when
> `GLOBIGNORE` is set and not null. However, setting `GLOBIGNORE` to a
> non-null value has the effect of enabling the `dotglob` shell option,
> so all other filenames beginning with a '`.`' will match. To get the
> old behavior of ignoring filenames beginning with a '`.`', make '`.*`'
> one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE`. The `dotglob` option is disabled
> when `GLOBIGNORE` is unset.

So the following will not include `foo.tex`, `bar.tex` or `baz.tex` in the wildcard expansion:

```
GLOBGIGNORE=foo.tex:bar.tex:baz.tex
grep ... *.tex
```

GNU `grep` also has its own ways for excluding files and directories, such as `--exclude-from` to take a file containing list of globs to exclude:

```
grep --exclude-from=<(printf "%s\n" "${excludedfiles[@]}") ...
```

Or `--exclude` to specify each glob individually:

```
declare -a grep_options
for f in "${excludedfiles[@]}"
do
    # add --exclude for each file
    grep_options+=(--exclude="$f")
done
grep "${grep_options[@]}" ...
```

Comment: Beware however that if you have `GLOBIGNORE=foo.tex`, that prevents `foo.tex` from being included in the expansion of `*.tex`, but not `./foo.tex` from being excluded from the expansion of `./*.tex` or `dir/foo.tex` from being excluded from the expansion of `**/*.tex`.  Same applies to GNU `grep`'s `--exclude*`. Those features are only usable to exclude some file extensions with patterns like `*.bak`, `*~`... See ksh's FIGNORE for a slightly better design. In bash, you generally need to revert the setting of dotglob. See also [there](/a/279448)

Comment: Also note that if the filenames you want to exclude contain wildcard characters or `:` or `` \ ``, you'll need to escape them, and since `bash` has no equivalent to `zsh`'s `b` parameter flag and since its `${var//pat/repl}` (contrary to that of ksh93/zsh) has no way to recall the matched part in the replacement, that's going to be quite painful.

Comment: @muru: I just wanted to confirm that you are suggesting two distinct ways to exclude a list of files here. Though you don't have a complete script in either case.

Comment: @Faheem yes, two distinct ways, `GLOBIGNORE` in bash and `--exclude` in grep. I believe the snippets given here are sufficient for understanding it's writing scripts is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple for-loop without arrays:

```
excludedfiles="foo.tex|bar.tex|baz.tex"

for i in $(ls *.tex | egrep -vx ${excludedfiles});do
  filename=$(grep -H "\\RequireLuaTeX" $i | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
  base=${filename%.*}
  if [[ "$base" == "" ]];then continue; fi
  rm -f "$base".pdf
  latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode  "$base".tex
done
```

What it does:

1. Looks for the files `.tex`
2. Filters out specified files (egrep)
3. Text-search specified pattern `\RequireLuaTeX` ("\\" to include \ in search)
4. Checks for empty variable `filename` and skips to next if empty (happens if grep doesn't find a match)
5. Finish with given commands

I recommend dry-running the script without the final `rm` and `latex` command and verify the output by "echo"ing `"$base"`. I can imagine problems with spaces in filenames (with every solution).

```
...
  if [[ "$base" == "" ]];then continue; fi
  echo $base
done
```

You can pull out all search-patterns and put them in a variable for better adjustment and easy-handling if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm impressed by the reduced linecount and improved efficiency of other answers, I'd like to offer a different approach which prioritizes simplicity of code.  This approach will make your future maintenance easier and reduce your errors and your time spent testing.

In practice, for cases like this, there is no noticeable difference in running time and the benefits of a reduced linecount are more than offset by the increased complication of the code involved, making it harder to find errors by code review in the shorter code.

```
#!/bin/bash

dryrun=false
[[ $1 = -n ]] && dryrun=true

bye() { >&2 printf "abort: %s\n" "$*"; exit 1; }

for f in *.tex ;do
  [[ $f = foo.tex || $f = bar.tex || $f = baz.tex ]] && continue
  grep -q '\\RequireLuaTeX' "$f" && continue
  if $dryrun ;then
    printf "dryrun: %s\n" "$f"
    continue
  fi
  rm -f "${f%.tex}.pdf" || bye rm
  latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode "$f" || bye latexmk
done
```